# PHP multiple input buttons with same textarea

Tags: php, html, excel, button, input

Could someone help me with such issue (I'm quite new at php, thus small help needed)...

I have a **text area**, where I can enter one or several project Nr's, and I want to have two buttons, which are working based on SQL query : first one will show results on a page, second one exports the data in Excel.

Part where data is being displayed on a web page directly is already working for me. But how can I make so, that based on the second input button (**Export to Excel**) it will trigger different part of code, but using same values from text area?

Currently my problem is that when I'm pressing second button it also triggers part of the code, where I'm showing data on a web page and I need to ignore that while exporting to excel.

Currently part of my HTML looks like :

```
<div>
    <form action="main" method="post">
        <textarea name="project1" cols="30" rows="5" type="submit" placeholder="Enter Project Number('s)"/></textarea>
        <input value=" Submit " type="submit"/> <!-- Shows on web page -->
        <input name="excel" type="submit" value=" Export to Excel " /> <!-- Exports to Excel -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: use isset() and give name for both button and check condition using button name . is it clear to you  ?

Comment: Textarea does not have a type yet alone a submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  Fred -ii has already pointed out, textarea doesn't have a type, it should be

```
<textarea name="project1" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Project Number('s)"/></textarea>
```

**Method 1**
If you want to have more than one submit button in the form, you can give each of them an unique name.
Once you have named them uniquely, you can check which parameter is set to perform different functions on the post to script.

**PHP**

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['displayPage'])){
        echo $_POST['project1'] . "<br />\n";
   }
   if(isset($_POST['excel'])) {
        //put your excel export script here"
   }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="displayPage" type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
<input name="excel" type="submit" value="Export to Excel" />
```

**Method 2**
Alternatively you can use the ***same name*** for **ALL** the buttons and perform function based on the ***value*** of the button.

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit"){
    echo $_POST['project1'] . "<br />\n";
 }
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Export to Excel"){
    //put your excel export script here
 }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Export to Excel" />
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks, first method works very good! Just additional question:
how can I trigger other part of php code on the second if ? 

for example, if I'm setting to the <form> action = "output.php" it applies to both buttons, but when I'm using include('output.php'); in the part of IF  - it exports me whole content of the page, with my CSS and other data...

Comment: you need to show us your php script. Actually that would be a different question altogether, perhaps it would be better if you open a new post. With 1) your PHP script 2) sample data of you are getting (do a screen shot or something)  3) your desired result

Answer (score 0):

I would use onclick event on the second button instead of type="submit".

```
<input name="excel" onclick="export()" value=" Export to Excel " /> <!-- Exports to Excel -->
```

And add a javascript code with this below code in your body tag:

```
<script>
   function export(){
   //your code to export Excel or your call to php
   }
</script>
```